# Javascript: способы создания объекта в объекте

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не удается добавить объект в объект если исходный пустой?

Например:

```
 obj = {};
 obj['options']['test2'] = 2;  // ошибка Cannot set property 'test2' of undefined
```

Однако, если перед этим создать объект с помощью присвоения:

```
 obj = {};
 obj['options'] = {test1:1};

 obj['options']['test2'] = 2;  //ошибки уже не возникает
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, оптимальные способы создания объекта в объекте. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому что данного объекта нету, следовательно подобное выражение вернёт `undefined` без предыдущего присваивания данного параметра.

```
return typeof options ["name"];
```

Для корректной работы нужно сначала создать объект, а уже только потом работать с его параметрами.

```
options ["name"] ["parameter"] = typeof value; // так работать не будет

options ["name"] = {}; 
options ["name"] ["parameter"] = typeof value; // а так все будет работать
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> obj['options']['test2'] = 2;  // ошибка Cannot set property 'test2' of undefined
> ```

Текст ошибки прямо описывает проблему: `obj.options` на момент присваивания не определён.

Одним из решений может быть предварительная проверка:

```
if (typeof obj.options === 'undefined') obj.options = {};
obj.options.test2 = 2;
```

Comment: Можно и без typeof.